# What is the Vue Options API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-options-api

I know that one of the main features of Vue 3 is the Composition API, which is an alternative to the old Vue Options API. But I can't seem to find a simple text definition of the Options API - what is it?

Comment: Maybe this article can help: https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/vue-3-composition-api-vs-options-api/

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-api.html

read this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short from the [blog article about composition vs. options API](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/vue-3-composition-api-vs-options-api/), which I posted in the comments:

```js
// Options API
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'John',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    doIt() {
      console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.doIt();
  },
};
```

```js
// Composition API
export default {
  setup() {
    const name = ref('John');
    
    const doIt = () => console.log(`Hello ${name.value}`);
    
    onMounted(() => {
      doIt();
    });
    
    return { name };
  },
};
```

Options API is the name for the "old" way from Vue2. AFAIK you can still use both as if it was the olden times of Vue2.

I had to click on the 6th link when searching for *"vue options api"* - so pretty far down in the search results but at least not unfindable (a.k.a. Google search results, page 2).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I was looking for a text summary of what it is rather than the syntax.

Comment: The difference in syntax is what it is

Comment: don't mix the two in the same component though, impossible to fix bugs will happen